# Expose 2-dimensional array to QML grid

Tags: c++, qt, mvvm, qml

I'm writing a simple Snake game to practice the MVVM pattern and good design and practice in general. As of now I'm finished with the model, so I want to move over to the view model and GUI part.

My game board is a class `Field` which holds a `std::vector<std::vector<state>>` member with `state` being the state the respective cell is in - it can be `state::empty` or `state::fruit` at the moment.

How would I expose this to QML and how would I access it in QML?

Same question goes for my `Snake` class, which has a member of type `std::list<std::pair<int, int>>` - a list containing the coordinates of the field cells the snake is currently on.

Comment: Write a model wrapper for it, then you can use that with the standard QML views.

Comment: That is what I'm having trouble with. Could you give me some sort of template as an orientation, please?

Comment: Check QAbstractItemModel - it is pretty straightforward, there are a few methods you need to implement for getting the size, roles and data

Comment: This question is too much open...